# Select from SAP HANA Database via JDBC with Parameters

Tags: sql, jdbc, hana

I got a query-view on a native SAP HANA database on which i want to perform a select-statement.

The SELECT statement is sent by a third-party BI tool which uses the SAP HANA JDBC Driver (ngdbc.jar) to perform the access to the HANA database.

The query expects two input parameters: PARAMETER_A and PARAMETER_B

On the native HANA database the syntax would look like this (SAP HANA Studio):

```
select *
from "_SYS_BIC"."QUERY_VIEW" ('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$PARAMETER_A$$', 'value_1'), 'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$PARAMETER_B$$', 'value_2'))
```

When I try to perform this query via JDBC I get this syntax error:

> the '=' sign is not allowed.

Can anybody tell me the correct syntax in case of JDBC?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post your JAVA code so that we can see how you construct the SQL string that you send to HANA?

Comment: Hello Lars, there is no JAVA code. We use a third party BI-tool. This tool allows an import from a SAP HANA data source using a JDBC-driver (ngdbc.jar).

So we can post our select-SQL-statement into the import-wizard of the BI-tool and select the driver which should be used to access the data source.

I tried the select-statement which is shown in my first posting and which is working fine in the "SAP HANA Studio". But when I use this statement in the BI-Tool (which uses JDBC to access the HANA-database) it shows an syntax-error which states that the '=' is not allowed...

Comment: Therefore, I suspect that the JDBC driver expects a different specification of the parameters?!

Comment: I cannot confirm your suspicion. SAP HANA Studio practically uses the same JDBC driver than the one you can download and install from the client package. To me it seems, that a) either your BI-tool tries to evaluate the SQL syntax itself and fails as the `PLACEHOLDER...` syntax is very HANA specific or b) the SQL string is not quoted properly by the BI-tool before sending it to HANA.

Comment: BTW: which third-party-BI-tool are you using here?

Answer (score 0):

As Lars said HANA uses same JDBC driver as third party tools, just version can be different. To check how JDBC call is looks like, you can turn on trace log in HANA studio, see [here](https://www.stechies.com/trace-hana-studio-jdbc-activities/)

In your log you would see, something like:

```
com.sap.db.jdbc.HanaConnectionFinalize@37c52b05[ID:316971].prepareCall("SELECT top 10 ""VAR_SUM""
FROM ""_SYS_BIC"".""CV_TEST""('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_VAP_1$$', '5'), 'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_VAR_2$$', '3'))", 1003, 1007)
```

so you should setup trace for your BI-tool and check the difference between how it's executed SELECT statement and HANA studio.
Hope it helps ))